# random class event, changes all the classes to same name

Tags: javascript

I have a dice application with a roll function, the roll function is suppose to roll the dices inside the application, well the function is rolling them, but it print out all the dices the same. something like this. 
If i have 4 dices with value

1-4-7-3 , when i roll them, the answer will be a random nr lets say 6, then all the 6 dices output 6-6-6-6 .

Tips ?

```
  function rollEvent(){ 
        var rollDices = "roll"; 
        var addClass= document.getElementsByClassName(rollDices); 
        addClass=addClass[addClass.length-1]; 
        addClass.addEventListener("click", rollDice, true); 
        var diceArray = Array=[ 
        "dice dice-side-one", 
        "dice dice-side-two", 
        "dice dice-side-three", 
        "dice dice-side-four", 
        "dice dice-side-five", 
        "dice dice-side-six"]; 
        function rollDice(e) { 
            var name = diceArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * diceArray.length)]; 
            var obj=e.target; 
            var elementToRemove = " dice-window-wrapper "; 
            while((" "+obj.className+" ").indexOf(elementToRemove)==-1){ 
                obj=obj.parentNode; 
            } 

            var allDiceInWindow=obj.getElementsByClassName("dice"); 


             for(var i = 0; i<allDiceInWindow.length; i++){

                  allDiceInWindow[i].className = name;

            }



        } 
    }
    rollEvent();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `Math.random()` method only once, then applying the result to all your dice. Try this for your `rollDice` method:

```
function rollDice(e) { 
    var obj=e.target; 
    var elementToRemove = " dice-window-wrapper "; 
    while((" "+obj.className+" ").indexOf(elementToRemove)==-1){ 
        obj=obj.parentNode; 
    }
    var allDiceInWindow=obj.getElementsByClassName("dice"); 

    for(var i = 0; i<allDiceInWindow.length; i++){
        // set the name individually for each die
        var name = diceArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * diceArray.length)]; 
        allDiceInWindow[i].className = name;
    }
}
```